# Residues with Inequalities

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

If $f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)|\leq A|z|$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ for some fixed $A>0$, then can I write $$\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-c)^n}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{A|z|dz}{|z-c|^n}=\frac{A}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to c}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\right)^{n-1}|z|$$
The differentiation part is making me doubt that I can do this.

Comment: Sorry, I typed it in incorrectly.  Please see the correction.

Comment: You are proving a corollary of Liouville's theorem, yes?

Comment: the bound on $|\int g(z)\,\text{d}z|$ ought to be $\int |g(z)|\;|\text{d}z|$, which is not $\int |g(z)|\,\text{d}z$. Maybe @FShrike could find a specific reference for this, so that the OP can check it out?

Comment: @ChrisSanders Point 1) I did not actually notice the OP was writing it themselves, so I didn’t check for errors like that! Point 2) unfortunately some authors write $\mathrm{d} z$ *anyway*, without the $|\cdot|$, which once caused me a whole half hour of frustrated staring at a Wikipedia page trying to make sense of it... :)

Comment: *Caused? I meant cost

Comment: Anyway, if you are looking for a proof that $f$ entire and $|f(z)|\le M|z|$ for some $M\ge0$ constant implies $f$ is linear, I can provide that if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both the inequality and the equality in your statement are without justification.

For the bound on $\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-c)^n}\right|$,

use either the [Estimation Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) or some better bound related to the lemma.

As for $\int_\gamma\frac{G(z)dz}{(z-c)^n}$, where $G(z)$ is NOT analytic,

the integral formulae to which you were implicitly referring don't apply.

Comment: Nice. $|z|$ not analytic is an important point I neglected

Comment: Thank you, I realise now that I should have been using the "estimation lemma" that you have mentioned.